# Update GET request in Dajax

Tags: python, django, dajaxice, dajax

I am trying to make it possible to update search results with Dajax as you change the search parameters. I have a GET request for the word search, and would like to modify it using Dajax.

I understand this query has to be in POST format, but how can I combine the word search (currently GET) with the additional parameters (POST)?

So far I am trying this, where variable 'request' is the GET request.

```
<p onClick="Dajaxice.myapp.get_by_topic(request,{'data':{'mytopic':this.innerHTML}});">mytopic</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dajax project is pretty much dead.  He said it himself on the Github page. https://github.com/jorgebastida/django-dajax/  It really offers nothing you're not capable of accomplishing on your own using a simple form post with jquery ajax.

Why not post your search form to your view method using jquery Ajax which returns JSON and display that in your search results?  You can make the post on every space or every few letters etc...

It may take some playing around with to get used to, but you're better off doing that than learning a dead library.